# Read binary file from database but don't save it

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I wrote a windows form program in VB

In the from of my Project I want if a button is clicked, show a file (pdf or word) that save in database. I use this code for doing it and this code works fine. but files are copied in my bin folder of project. I want that these files only show on screen but not saved anywhere. Can anyone help me?

```
            Try
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While dr.Read()
                        Dim size As Integer = 1024 * 1024
                        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(size - 1) {}
                        Dim readBytes As Integer = 0
                        Dim index As Integer = 0
                        filename = dr("DocName")
                        Using fs As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)

                            While (InlineAssignHelper(readBytes, CInt(dr.GetBytes(0, index, buffer, 0, size)))) > 0
                                fs.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes)
                                index += readBytes
                            End While
                        End Using
                    End While
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim errMessageBox As New Puzzle.ErrorHandler
                errMessageBox.ShowError("Err", "FrmCustomer:DbTools_GetAttachFile", "line", ex.Message)
                Exit Sub
            Finally
                ConImage.Close()
            End Try
        End Using

        Dim prc As New Process()
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = filename
        prc.Start()
```

Comment: How do you suppose the program can show the file if you don't save it to disk? You could use the temporary folder for it though.

Comment: Use a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream`.

Comment: @venerik That won't work because he wants to start a new process with that filename.

Comment: @Drik how can I use temporary folder for it?

Comment: To get a temporary filename, you can use `Dim tempFileName As String = IO.Path.GetTempFileName`

Comment: @PradeepKumar how can i save file in temporary folder when read from DB?

Comment: I just posted in the answer which line to modify. Just check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the following line, and it should work.

```
'filename = dr("DocName")             ' replace this line
filename = IO.Path.GetTempFileName    ' with this
```

Basically, `IO.Path.GetTempFileName` will get a temporary filename in the Windows `Temp` folder. This folder is used for keeping temporary files and is usually cleaned by various disk cleaning tools automatically or when you ask windows to reclaim wasted space (via Disk Cleanup program).

Note that you would need the same `filename` when opening the file.

Comment: i repalce this code but in  prc.Start() line have this err : windows can not open this file

Comment: I use this code and it work : IO.Path.GetTempPath + dr("DocName")

Comment: Just as I said in my answer, you must specify the same filename when starting the process. Your earlier code was looking in the bin folder (the default if path is not specified). You haven't shown that code, and I don't know the scope of your `filename` variable, whether declared local or at class level.

Comment: thnaks. Can I remove this file from temp in my project?

Comment: okk.. that's great. Then use `IO.Path.Combine` instead of using `+` to concatinate the path and filename. This way you don't have to worry about path separator. `IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath, dr("DocName"))`

Comment: Yes, once you know that file is no longer in use, you can safely remove it without any problems.